# jqm change position of collapsible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, position, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I just want to change the position of collapsible `col2` before collapsible`col1`. Finally the order should be: 1.`col2` 2.`col1` 3.`col3`

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="List" data-role="collapsible-set">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="c" id="col1">
            <h3>Header 1</h3>
            <p>Text 1</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="c" id="col2">
            <h3>Header 2</h3>    
            <p>Text 2</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="c" id="col3">
            <h3>Header 3</h3>    
            <p>Text 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should tell in your question what have you tried so far. I think you could use this to move and then refresh the collapsible $('#col1').after($('#col2')); $('#List').collapsible('refresh')

Comment: @sergioFC post an answer, get some rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the collapsible and then call refresh:

```
$('#col1').after($('#col2')); // Move the node
$('#List').collapsibleset('refresh'); // Refresh the collapsible set
```

**Edited**: the 'refresh' method should be called in the collapsibleset plugin (not on the collapsible plugin). -Thanks Omar for the correction.

Comment: `.collapsibleset('refresh')`